# perl script to translate input to JSON

Tags: json, perl

Sorry, I am very new to JSON and wanted to write a Perl script which can translate few inputs into JSON (below format). The values to be read are "name", "location", "job" are so on.. There would also sub resource types to be defined which should constructed in following way..

What would be the best way to input or read these properties and values? Would that a simple text file or an excel with each property (name, location etc..)?  Any suggestions?

```
[{
"name":"James Anderson"
"location":"States"
"qualifier":{ 
    "job":"auto dealer"
    "experience":"20"
            },
          "Children": [
            {
                "name":"Mark Brown"
                "age":"15"
            }
                      "education": {
                          "college":"University of Texas"
                                   }      
            {
                "name":"Steve Brown" 
                "age":"10"
            }
                      ]
}
{
"name":"Mark Jones"
"location":"London"
"qualifier":{ 
    "country":"UK"
    "job":"business"
    "citizen":"no"
             }
}
]
```

Comment: This really isn't a duplicate of the other question… but it is hopelessly subjective so shouldn't be reopened.